# Does Solr 4.3.1 run on Java 8

Tags: solr4

We are still using Solr 4.3.1, Java 7 and JBoss 7. Just trying to upgrade to Java 8 without upgrading Solr at the moment. Solr admin does not start though, Solr log is absent and I see no error in any log.

Could someone confirm that Solr 4.3. does not work using Java 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to wrap up. Solr 4.8.1 officially support Java 8. At this point, I am migrating to Solr 5 though.